# Sequence of runOnUiThread and sendKeys calls leading to NPE on Android

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, android-testing

I am new to Android and JUnit testing.
I am trying to come up with some test cases for the MyFirstApp example as explained here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Here is how my test class looks like:

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

    mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();

    editText = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(
                             com.example.myfirstapp.R.id.edit_message);
    button = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(
                             com.example.myfirstapp.R.id.button1);

}

public void testPreconditions(){
    assertTrue(editText.getHint().toString().equals(
                  mainActivity.getString(
                      com.example.myfirstapp.R.string.edit_message)));
}


public void testUI(){
    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            editText.performClick();

        }
    });
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E);



    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.performClick();

        }
    });
}
```

The testPrecontions test succeeds. However this gives NPE for "button.performClick();"

Can someone please point out what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks
-Angshu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out there needed to be added the call to `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()` after the 2nd runOnUiThread call as in the following

```
public void testUI(){

    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            editText.performClick();

        }
    });

    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D);
    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E);



    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.performClick();

        }
    });
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else stuck in a similar situation.

Thanks all!
-Angshu

Comment: that would be my next sugestion, you can also accept your own answer to show, that the question is succesfull answered.

Answer (score 0):

The button has no assigned ID, so `#findViewByID` returns `null` and you can't call `performClick()` on a `null-Object`.

this should be your GUI-Declaration (copied from the tutorial), right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

add in the ID Attribute for the Button, like by the EditText, this should fix the Error on the View lookup:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Comment: I do have the id for button in the xml file. This is a bit strange because if I do performClick on the button in the first call to runOnUiThread the test succeeds, it only seems to fail in the successive calls to  runOnUiThread. I mean while testUI above fails at button.performClick(), the following runs to success:


    `public void testUI(){
  mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
    editText.performClick();
    button.performClick();
    
   }
  });
  getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
  
 }`

Am I doing something wrong? Please help